# Binding two dataframes based on the intersection of two columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi guys I am trying to bind two data frames when there is a match between two columns in R.

```
X.1 <- runif(5)
X.2 <- runif(5)
fruit <- c("apple","apple","banana","orange","orange")
month <- c("January","February","March","April","May")


fruit.second <- c("apple","apple","apple","banana","orange","orange")
month.second <- c("January","February","March","January","April","May")
Y.1 <- runif(6)
Y.2 <- runif(6)

df <- data.frame(X.1,X.2,as.character(fruit),as.character(month))
df


        X.1        X.2 as.character.fruit. as.character.month.
1 0.08694442 0.67541559               apple             January
2 0.50374582 0.04485657               apple            February
3 0.50482380 0.76090011              banana               March
4 0.75920285 0.61077744              orange               April
5 0.95243661 0.18064744              orange                 May  



df2 <- data.frame(as.character(fruit.second),as.character(month.second),Y.1,Y.2)
df2

  as.character.fruit.second. as.character.month.second.       Y.1       Y.2
1                      apple                    January 0.3407055 0.5740400
2                      apple                   February 0.1529912 0.8163872
3                      apple                      March 0.1042926 0.9807348
4                     banana                    January 0.1031409 0.7961291
5                     orange                      April 0.9537869 0.1840729
6                     orange                        May 0.3158263 0.8856582
```

I want to create a data frame that binds the two when fruit **AND** month match. So a data frame that contains the attributes(X.1,X.2,fruit,month,Y.1,Y.2) where fruit **and** month match. An example is the first two rows in both data frames. Those are matches. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: take a look at `merge`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the names of `fruit.second` and `month.second` in `df2` to `fruit` and `month` for convenience in the `by` argument of `merge`, but if you don't make that change you could just as easily do

```
merge(
  x=df,
  y=df2,
  by.x=c("fruit","month"),
  by.y=c("fruit.second","month.second")
)
```

instead of what is done below.

```
set.seed(1234)
X.1 <- runif(5)
set.seed(2345)
X.2 <- runif(5)
fruit <- c("apple","apple","banana","orange","orange")
month <- c("January","February","March","April","May")
##
fruit.second <- c("apple","apple","apple","banana","orange","orange")
month.second <- c("January","February","March","January","April","May")
set.seed(3456)
Y.1 <- runif(6)
set.seed(4567)
Y.2 <- runif(6)
##
df <- data.frame(
  X.1,X.2,
  fruit=as.character(fruit),
  month=as.character(month),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
##
df2 <- data.frame(
  fruit=as.character(fruit.second),
  month=as.character(month.second),
  Y.1,Y.2,
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
##
merge(
  df,
  df2,
  by=c("fruit","month")
)
##
   fruit    month       X.1       X.2       Y.1       Y.2
1  apple February 0.6222994 0.1950251 0.7618600 0.7412554
2  apple  January 0.1137034 0.1167435 0.7785807 0.2309186
3 orange    April 0.6233794 0.0344546 0.5071998 0.5996399
4 orange      May 0.8609154 0.4751201 0.7980290 0.2773313
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a data.table approach. If your real dataset is large, then this will be *much* faster than `merge(...)` with data frames.

*Note:* the important bit is the four lines at the end. Note also that data.table doesn't care that `fruit` and `month` are factors.

```
set.seed(1)   # for reproducible example
X.1 <- runif(5)
X.2 <- runif(5)
fruit <- c("apple","apple","banana","orange","orange")
month <- c("January","February","March","April","May")

fruit.second <- c("apple","apple","apple","banana","orange","orange")
month.second <- c("January","February","March","January","April","May")
Y.1 <- runif(6)
Y.2 <- runif(6)

df <- data.frame(X.1,X.2,fruit,month)
df2 <- data.frame(fruit.second,month.second,Y.1,Y.2)

## This does the work.
library(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(df,  key="fruit,month")
DT2 <- data.table(df2, key="fruit.second,month.second")
DT1[DT2,nomatch=0]
#     fruit    month       X.1        X.2       Y.1       Y.2
# 1:  apple February 0.3721239 0.94467527 0.1765568 0.9919061
# 2:  apple  January 0.2655087 0.89838968 0.2059746 0.7176185
# 3: orange    April 0.9082078 0.62911404 0.7698414 0.9347052
# 4: orange      May 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.4976992 0.2121425
```

Here's another way that's slightly more efficient in theory (but a bit more obtuse in code).

```
setkey(setDT(df),fruit,month)
setkey(setDT(df2),fruit.second,month.second)
df[df2,nomatch=0]
```

This approach converts `df` and `df2` to data.tables "by reference" which means, loosely, without making a copy. Then `setkey(...)` sorts them and sets the keys appropriately. Then `df[df2,...]` does the join. Using `nomatch=0` excludes rows that don't have matching values in the key columns (an inner join, in database terminology).

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a `join` operation, such as is implemented efficiently in the `dplyr` package.

There are 4 or 5 types of join operations, look in the doc or vignette which is the right one. You might have to modify the name of you columns, in order to use the join operation that matches based of identity of column names.